# Phone Auth with Firebase Flutter

Tags: android, firebase, flutter, dart

Estou tentando configurar o Phone Auth no Flutter mas não encontrei nada de útil para o meu caso.

Alguém teria alguma solução para isso?

Já conferi os dados do firebase SHA1 nome do pacote do app e está tudo correto, baixei o google-services atualizado, atualizei o firebase_auth porém continuo tendo esse problema, alguém que passou pelo mesmo problema teria a solução?

Estou tendo esses erros quando tento enviar o código para o número informado:

```
2019-06-29 16:54:24.061 13560-13560/com.zotinfo.diskhamburguerapp W/BiChannelGoogleApi: [FirebaseAuth: ] getGoogleApiForMethod() returned Gms: com.google.firebase.auth.api.internal.zzal@95837bb
2019-06-29 16:54:24.513 13560-13584/com.zotinfo.diskhamburguerapp I/flutter: Phone number verification failed. Code: firebaseAuth. Message: This app is not authorized to use Firebase Authentication. Please verifythat the correct package name and SHA-1 are configured in the Firebase Console. [ App validation failed ]
```

Comment: Que estranho se você já conferiu todos os dados. Chegou a confirmar também as configurações de inicialização do firebase? Outras coisas do firebase funcionam normalmente?

Comment: Sim já consegui fazer funcionar, faltava uma configuração, o SHA1 de debug, o que tinha configurado no Firebase era o SHA1 de lançamento.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Consegui resolver utilizando a versão mais recente, com Credentials.

Se alguém quiser utilizar dessa maneira está aqui o código:

```
Future<void> verificaPhone() async {
    try {
      final phoneNumber = "+55" +
          _phoneNumberController.text.replaceAll("(", "")
              .replaceAll(")", "")
              .replaceAll("-", "");
      if(_phoneNumberController.text.length > 13) {

        final PhoneVerificationCompleted verificationCompleted =
            (AuthCredential phoneAuthCredential) {
          _auth.signInWithCredential(phoneAuthCredential);

          Navigator.of(context).pushReplacement(
              MaterialPageRoute(builder: (context) => ConfereCadastro()));
          print('Auto login realizado: user');
//          setState(() {
//            Navigator.of(context).pushReplacement(
//                MaterialPageRoute(builder: (context) => ConfereCadastro()));
//            print('Auto login realizado: user');
//          });
        };

        final PhoneVerificationFailed verificationFailed = (
            AuthException authException) {
          print('Verificação para o número ${phoneNumber
              .toString()} falhou. Código: ${authException
              .code}. Motivo: ${authException.message}');
//          setState(() {
//            print('Verificação para o número ${phoneNumber
//                .toString()} falhou. Código: ${authException
//                .code}. Motivo: ${authException.message}');
//          });
        };

        final PhoneCodeSent codeSent =
            (String verificationId, [int forceResendingToken]) async {
          this.verificationId = verificationId;
          print("Código enviado para " + phoneNumber);
          setState(() => codigoEnviado = true);
        };

        final PhoneCodeAutoRetrievalTimeout codeAutoRetrievalTimeout =
            (String verificationId) {
          this.verificationId = verificationId;
          setState(() => codigoEnviado = false);
          print("Tempo limite esgotado!");
        };

        await FirebaseAuth.instance.verifyPhoneNumber(
            phoneNumber: phoneNumber,
            timeout: const Duration(seconds: 30),
            verificationCompleted: verificationCompleted,
            verificationFailed: verificationFailed,
            codeSent: codeSent,
            codeAutoRetrievalTimeout: codeAutoRetrievalTimeout);
      }
    } catch (e) {
      print("_signInWithPhoneNumber ERROR: ${e.toString()}");
    }

  }

  Future<void> _signInWithPhoneNumber(String smsCode) async {
    if(hasConnection == true) {
      try {
        AuthCredential credential = PhoneAuthProvider.getCredential(verificationId: verificationId, smsCode: smsCode);

        final FirebaseUser user = await _auth.signInWithCredential(credential);
        print('Usuário logado com sucesso $user');
        Navigator.of(context).pushReplacement(
            MaterialPageRoute(builder: (context) => ConfereCadastro()));
      } catch (e) {
        print("verificaPhone ERROR: ${e.toString()}");
      }
    } else {
      checkInternet();
    }
  }
```